# What is the reason behind the difference in Results?

Tags: matlab, math

let `x = [1 2 3;4 5 6]` then why `norm(x,2)` is different from `norm(x(:),2)`

`norm(x,2) = 9.5080` and `norm(x(:),2)=9.5394`.

I have run this program in Matlab R2012a.

Comment: it seems like you are not interested in tagging properly. Please add a tag for mathematics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As defined in Matlab help for norm, the returned value is "The largest singular value" for matrices, and `sum(abs(A).^2)^(1/2)` for vectors.

Additional reading:
[wikipedia - matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)

Answer (score 3):

`x(:)` is a vector, see what Matlab returns if you simply type that at the command-line. `x` is a matrix.  The 2-norm of a matrix and the 2-norm of a vector are calculated in different ways, in general the 2-norm of the vector of the elements of an array will not be the same as the 2-norm of the array.  For details see [good old Golub and Van Loan](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computations-Hopkins-Studies-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0801854148/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341411459&sr=1-1).

Why are the 2-norms of matrices and arrays different ?  That's maths and therefore off-topic here on SO so I daren't answer.